# AlertDialog Not working, During if conditional statement

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Whenever I leave my EditText's blank, and click on my compute button, the app crashes.

I have a conditional statement that checks for empty EditTexts and displays an AlertDialog (Message Box) if any of them are empty. However, for some reason, the AlertDialog is not working. I believe i have done everything correctly, but it is always good to get a second pair of eyes, that is what is actually done in the engineering world. So, do you see anything wrong with my code?

This is all done in my onClick method:

```
 if (interest.getText().equals("") || price.getText().equals("") || dwnPymnt.getText().equals("")
                || numYears.getText().equals("")) {
            /*
            Check if any of the input fields are blank during the tapping button process
             */
            AlertDialog.Builder warningMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            warningMessage.setMessage("Please make sure that no input fields are empty!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog warningAlert = warningMessage.create();
            warningAlert.setTitle("Empty Field(s)");
            warningAlert.show();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the logs? It will tell you the line the app crashed on.

Comment: *I believe i have done everything correctly...* - and I have used a debugger to step through my code, but alas the problem remains, - *it is always good to get a second pair of eyes.* — You left out that middle part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `toString()` to get a String object to invoke the `equals` function of `String` class

```
interest.getText().toString().equals("")
//                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note : do the same for rest of the conditions

Comment: Excellent, you are correct. That was the problem! Unfortunately, I can only mark your answer as correct in 8 minutes.

Comment: i am glad that i could help , you can accept the answer later or whenever you have time , happy coding